# Git Error code: No refs in common and none specified; doing nothing

Tags: railstutorial.org

I am following the rails tutorial and got stuck on chapter 1.4.3 Bitbucket. 
https://www.railstutorial.org/book/beginning#sec-bitbucket
This is what I have written and the answer I get.

```
pellem@rails-tutorial:~/workspace/hello_app (master) $ git remote add origin git@bitbucket.org:pellemartenson/hello_app.git
fatal: remote origin already exists.

pellem@rails-tutorial:~/workspace/hello_app (master) $ git push -u origin --all                                                          
No refs in common and none specified; doing nothing.
Perhaps you should specify a branch such as 'master'.
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
Everything up-to-date
```

I found some similar questions and tried some of the suggestion. But It doesn't work for me or I don't understand the answer.

Comment: Have you tried: git push -u origin master

Comment: This is what happens when I try that:

$ git push -u origin master
error: src refspec master does not match any.
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@bitbucket.org:pellemartenson/hello_app.git'

Answer (score 49):

If using bit bucket, it takes certain steps for granted and as such can give you lot of pain.
But here is how I fixed this issue.
In your root directory of your project

```
    git init
    git add .
    git commit -m "message"
```

Then follow the steps from the initial page of the repo

```
    git remote add origin https://xxxx@bitbucket.org/xxx/xxx.git
    git push -u origin --all
    git push -u origin --tags
```

Hope I've helped someone!

Comment: git commit - m "message" should be git commit -m "message", without any space in between the dash(-) and m. Just a typo.

Comment: This also helped me on the initial setup of visual studio team services creating and pushing a local project to their site.

Answer (score 9):

I think you forgot to commit. You have an empty local repository.

Comment: Wow, I spent 1 hour to solve this problem and your suggestion was right on - i just forgot to 'git commit -m "initial commit". Many thanks!

Comment: Thank god!. You were right!. Thx!!

Answer (score 3):

this works:

git push -f -u origin master

Answer (score 0):

You can have a try:

```
git push -f -u origin master
```

Comment: Ok. This is what happens then:
pellem@rails-tutorial:~/workspace/hello_app (master) $ git push -f -u origin master
error: src refspec master does not match any.
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@bitbucket.org:pellemartenson/hello_app.git'

Shall I be in my hello_app directory ro doesn´t that matter?
I have never entered my password. Shouldnt I? Or don't I need that when I have the public key? Just some thoughts.

Thanks for all suggestions!

Comment: git push -f should never be used.  It destroys the history of your repository. Commits should be additive, not destructive.

Comment: No more ideas about this? I am stuck,

Comment: I manage to solve it when I went through everything again from the beginning. Not really sure what I missed.